# Can't connect to my openshift application through filezilla

Tags: ssh, openshift, ssh-keys, openssh, filezilla

I was able for past projects to connect through filezilla. I followed each time this tutorial: https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/

Now, on my newly created application I cannot connect. I get these errors:

```
Error:  Server sent disconnect message
Error:  type 2 (protocol error):
Error:  "Too many authentication failures for 56420afe7628e1bc3d0001b3"
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Thanks

EDIT: Its interesting because now I check some of my other websites wich were stored in filezilla site manager and 3 of the 8 have the same error. I have't modified anything to them. I tried with another FTP client (WINSCP) and all the sites work fine. I updated filezilla to the latest version and I still have errors. I can't explain myself why some sites work and some others simply doesn't work anymore without making any change...

Comment: usually this means ssh is looking for keys and can't find them. Can you specify in filezilla which keys to use? If so, make sure you pick the correct ones. Maybe you can also specify to just use password login and not keys. Either way it depends on what you can tell filezilla.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a screenshot of the settings you are using?  Make sure to censor any sensitive information.

Comment: @three considering the filzilla connection tutorial I posted above you can see the connection type is through ssh so I have to connect using a .ppk which I checked several times and is correct.

Comment: @corey112358 Its interesting because now I check some of my oter websites wich were stored in filezilla site manager and 3 of the 8 have the same error. I have't modified anything to them. I tried with another FTP client (WINSCP) and all the sites work. I updated filezilla to the latest version and I still have errors. I can't explain myself why some sites work and some others simply doesn't work anymore without any change...

Comment: @AlexStanese, Sounds like you may need to check out the FileZilla community for help with that.  Is it possible that you were using keys that you have since deleted?

Comment: @corey112358 It's no way I've done that and to confirm I created new keys which have the same simptoms. I also tagged this post with filezilla.